# Java .txt open using default editor and scroll/seek

Tags: java, file, filesystems

In order to open a file (.TXT in my case) in default editor using Java, I am using

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().edit(file);
```

> Is it possible to move the pointer to a specific line in the default editor?

I feel it might depend on default editor (if it exposes such functionality) but any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: Even if you could execute the editor directly, this would require the editor to provide support for this feature in some meaningful way, which is unlikely for all the combinations of editors that are available...

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the editor to provide the functionality. You may be able to use something like AutoIt to gain window focus and automate key/mouse strokes to get the desired effect though.